# R e1071: Balanced Error Rate (BER) as error criterion in tune function

Tags: r, parameters, machine-learning, classification, knn

I'm kind of new to R and machine learning in general, so apologies if this seems stupid!

I'm using the e1071 package to tune the parameters of various models. My dataset is very unbalanced and I would like for the error criterion to be Balanced Error Rate... NOT overall classification error. However, I'm stumped as how to achieve this.

**Here is my code:**

```
#Find optimal value 'k' value for k-NN model (feature subset).
c <- data_train_sub[1:13]
d <- data_train_sub[,14]
knn2 <- tune.knn(c, d, k = 1:10, tunecontrol = tune.control(sampling = "cross", performances = TRUE, sampling.aggregate = mean)
)
summary(knn2)
plot(knn2)
```

**Which returns this:**

```
Parameter tuning of ‘knn.wrapper’:

- sampling method: 10-fold cross validation 

- best parameters:
 k
 1

- best performance: 0.001190476 

- Detailed performance results:
    k       error  dispersion
1   1 0.001190476 0.003764616
2   2 0.005952381 0.006274360
3   3 0.003557423 0.005728122
4   4 0.005924370 0.008352124
5   5 0.005938375 0.008407043
6   6 0.005938375 0.008407043
7   7 0.007128852 0.008315090
8   8 0.009495798 0.009343555
9   9 0.008305322 0.009751997
10 10 0.008319328 0.009795292
```

Has anyone any experience of altering the error being assessed in this function?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `class.weights` argument of the `svm()` function:

> a named vector of weights for the different classes, used for asymmetric class sizes...

Coefficient can easily be calculated as such:

```
class.weights = table(Xcal$species)/sum(table(Xcal$species))
```